# Msi & exe singing Microsoft Authenticode requirments

Tags: wpf, winforms, deployment, wix

I am trying to sign my small application, [following this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699202.aspx):

In the tutorial they did not ask me to purchase Microsoft Authenticode Certificates

I need to Removes "Unknown Publisher" security warnings; after I signmy msi and exe files I still have "Unknown Publisher"

Can I sign my msi or exe without purchasing [Microsoft Authenticode Certificates](https://www.sslshopper.com/microsoft-authenticode-certificates.html)?

I know that I can sign Java, Authenticode, and AIR apps free: https://www.globalsign.com/en/code-signing/code-signing-tool/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't remove "Unknown Publisher" security warnings without purchasing a code signing certificate.

The tutorial link describes how to create a test certificate. Quoting the first paragraph "If you use a test (self-created) certificate, the installation dialogs will display an "Unknown publisher" message."

When you purchase a code signing certificate, the certifying authority takes certain steps to verify your identity.  If those steps are passed, the certifying authority issues you a certificate signed by their private key.  The private key is kept secret.  When you install code signed software, the operating system extracts the code signature from the software and validates it against the public key provided by the certifying authority.  This is a simplification, the actual check involves a chain of certificates.  But the key point is: if you use a self signed test certificate, the operating system has no knowledge of the public key of the self signed test certificate so cannot validate against it.